# CASE tool with decision support systems features

Tags: software-development, case

I'm looking for a Computer-Aided Software Engineering (CASE) tool that has features of Decision Support Systems (DSS), particularly tools dedicated to managing software requirements, but more generic CASE tools (dedicated to the entire development process, not only the Requirements Engineering phase) are welcome too.

I already know the [IBM Rational Requisite PRO](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/tnd/search.jsp?pn=Rational+RequisitePro), but I'm not looking for alternatives, I'm looking for other CASE tools that may (or may not) be totally different, since that have DSS functions.

For DSS function, I mean (not mandatory, just examples):

- Reports that helps a decision maker in a requirement inclusion/exclusion;
- Generation of requirements from plaintext (text processing);
- Automatic generation of traceability artefacts (linking requirements to other software artifacts);
- Tools to automate the generation of software documentation;
- Etc;

Commercial tools or open source projects are both welcome. Web or desktop.

**Background**:
Just to clarify my needs, I'm working on a comparative study of CASE tools that has DSS functions and academic tools are easy to find (thanks Google Scholar), but I can't find commercial tools used in the "real word" in companies.